# Can't reset MySQL Server Root password due to mysql database being gone

Tags: mysql

I forgot my root password.

I take the following steps:

1. Stop service
2. run "mysqld --skip-grant-tables &"
3. run "use mysql;" to try and reset the user table

Error 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mysql'

Is this fixable? I tried reinstalling and it didn't help.